# JavaScript function call/apply with string

Tags: javascript, function, call, this, apply

I just noticed that, when I want to pass string as `"this"`, the type cannot be obtained correctly inside a JavaScript function.

Here is an example:

```
var str = 'string value';
if (typeof (str) == 'string') {
    alert('string outside');
}

var fn = function(s) {
    if (typeof (str) == 'string') {
        alert('string param');
    }

    if (typeof (this) == 'string') {
        alert('string this');
    }
    else {
        alert(typeof(this));
    }
};

fn.call(str, str);
```

I see 3 messages: `"string outside"`, `"string param"`, and `"object"`.

My goal is to write an `"if"` statement that says `"this"` is string. Something like `if (typeof(this) == 'string')`. This one does not work, please point me to the correct statement that will work inside the function.

Comment: what is the end game?

Comment: I want to know, if "this" is string. I don't have param in the real code, just "this", so no alternative.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with that? `this` is the `window` object in there. Or better yet, _Why_ do you need to check if `this` is a string? It'll _never_  be a string.

Comment: I want to know, if the caller intended to pass string (even though now that looks as object with characters inside).

Comment: why do you want to know that `this` is a string?

Comment: Because this is a function that may receive an object, an array, or a string, and behavior differs.

Comment: i would just create separate functions for each.

Comment: I would also, if that was a possibility.

Comment: why isn't it a possibility?

Comment: Because this is not a real code here. Condition is clear: I want to test "this".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primitive values are embedded as objects when they're used as context.

From [the MDN on the call function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) :

> Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the
>   method is a function in non-strict mode code, null and undefined will
>   be replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be
>   boxed.

If you want to know if the object is of type String, use :

```
var isString = Object.prototype.toString.call(str) == '[object String]';
```

This is the solution [the MDN recommends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) for object type detection.

Comment: Understood, thanks. Workaround? want to know that the caller intended to pass string.

Comment: This worked. Your answer will be accepted. Thanks! :-) first person who paid attention to the detail.

Comment: @dystroy where can I find documentation on `window.toString`? MDN seems to be lacking that one on [disambiguation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/toString).

Comment: Oh, apparently `window` derives from Object. This apparently won't work nicely in old IE though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669079/window-tostring-call-is-undefined-in-ie8

Comment: I am using Object.prototype.toString, I guess that will work always. This answer gave me a correct hint.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté If you apply [this](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8) and [this](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1) you find that [this function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) applies (there is no specific overriding). Note that the MDN mentions the same use than me (bottom of the page).

Comment: I see. Though the linked question above still applies, doesn't it? `window` is a host object and your `toString` assumes that it inherits the `Object` prototype. Better reference the `Object.prototype` directly for consistency with older browsers, not?

Answer (score 5):

[ES spec](http://es5.github.com/#x10.4.3) forces the `this` keyword to reference an object:

> 1. Else if Type(*thisArg*) is not Object, set the `ThisBinding` to `ToObject(thisArg)`.

One workaround using [`Object.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString):

```
Object.prototype.toString.call( this ) === '[object String]'
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/334Lz/2/)

Comment: Workaround? just want to know that string was attempted at least.

Comment: I'm not saying to modify, I'm saying to query, or distinguish.

Comment: You mean to test if the typeof is an Object String? Let me see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks this worked, but you were the second to give a correct answer. +1.

Comment: Alright thanks, took a little longer trying to find the correct Object prototype method. Didn't know window had a `window.toString` method, learning something new every day.

Comment: Oh I see, `window` inherits the Object prototype in modern browsers. Still better to reference the `Object.prototype` directly to be consistent in older browsers ([related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669079/window-tostring-call-is-undefined-in-ie8)). - just commenting here to don't leave any future reader wondering, more detailed discussion on @dystroy's answer if you haven't read already

Answer (score 0):

To access a function's parameters, you don't use `this`.

Try this instead:

```
var fn = function(s) {
    if (typeof (s) == 'string') { // "s" is your passed parameter there.
        alert('string param');
    }
};
```

(Apparently, you even specified a name for the passed parameter, already).

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/function.html) for the basics about functions and parameters.

Comment: This was for the example. I want to test "this". But I already got an answer that will be accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `typeof this` is `"object"` is because `this` must always point to an object. Here JavaScript is implicitly coercing the string to an object. What you want instead is the primitive value of the object. Try this:

```
var str = "string value";

if (typeof str === "string") alert("string outside");

function fn(str) {
    var type = typeof this.valueOf();
    if (typeof str === "string") alert("string param");
    if (type === "string") alert("string this");
    else alert(type);
};

fn.call(str, str);
```

Hope this helps. See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BuZuu/