# Remove an item from nested observableArray

Tags: knockout.js

Hey I am trying to remove a item from a inner(nested) observableArray as following, but the Remove Button doesn't work (for the inner foreach items).

http://jsfiddle.net/aDahT/1871/

html:

```
<h4>People</h4>
<ul data-bind="foreach: peoples">
    <li>
        Name at position <span data-bind="text: $index"> </span>:
        <span data-bind="text: name"> </span>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removePerson">Remove</a>
        <ul data-bind="foreach:people">
             <li>
                <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
                 <button data-bind="click: $parent.deletePerson">Remove</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<button data-bind="click: addPerson">Add</button>
```

Script:

```
var Person = function(name, children){
 var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.people =  ko.observableArray(children);
    self.deletePerson = function() {
        alert(JSON.stringify(self));
        self.people.remove(this);
    }
}


function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.peoples = ko.observableArray([
        new Person( 'Bert', ['baa', 'bbb'] ),
        new Person('Charles', ["caa", "cbb"] )
    ]);

    self.addPerson = function() {
        alert(this);
        self.peoples.push(new Person( "New" ,["Daa", "Dbb"] ));
    }.bind(this);

    self.removePerson = function() {

        self.peoples.remove(this);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the first parameter of your click handler which is always set to the current view model:

```
self.deletePerson = function(viewModel) {
    self.people.remove(viewModel);
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1gL4c7pk/).

Knockout also sets the `this` to the current viewmodel in your handlers but there is a big difference in your `deletePerson` and the `removePerson`.

In the `removePerson` the `this` is an object (your `Person` object) but in your `deletePerson` the this should be a primitive type: a **string**.

However Knockout uses `apply` to call your function and it boxes primitive types: [JavaScript function call/apply with string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027763/javascript-function-call-apply-with-string)

You check this if you log out `this` to the console. You will see something like:

```
String {0: "c", 1: "a", 2: "a", length: 3, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "caa"}
```

So you will end up a boxed string in your `deletePerson` in the `this` and you need to use `valueOf()` (or the `toString()`) to get its value:

```
self.deletePerson = function() {
    self.people.remove(this.valueOf());
}
```

So just always use the first parameter provided by KO which is always the original value.

Comment: Thanks! just another question, in this line  alert(JSON.stringify(self)); why it shows name value but not shows the values for people?

Comment: Beacuse `JSON.stringify` only shows primitive values and `people` is a function because it is an observable array. You need to use the `ko.toJSON()` to also get the values form people so you need to write: `alert(ko.toJSON(self));`

Comment: Thanks, that make perfect sense

Comment: Can you please help me here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54320140/knockout-remove-array-element-by-specific-field-value/54322415#54322415

Answer (score 0):

You can try also ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=jTx57Gc0OO)):

```
<ul data-bind="foreach:people">
<li>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    <button data-bind="click: function() {$parent.people.remove($data)}, text: 'remove ' + name"></button>
</li>
</ul>

var model = {
people: ko.observableArray([{ name: "a"}, { name: "b"}, { name: "c"}])
};

ko.applyBindings(model);
```