# What is the purpose of Object.prototype.toString()?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I see this code in [underscore.js.](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L28)

Here it is, with the alias applied:

```
toString = ObjProto.toString,
```

However, to use toString it is also accessible directly like this, w/ out using above code at all.

```
toString()
```

Try it out in the console it works fine.  Try it out in direct code and it works fine as well.  My guess is that older browsers may not have it accessible in this way.

How can I look into this further?

[Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/) does not not have information on it.

[Google](https://www.google.com/#sugexp=epsugrpqhmsignedin,hmss2=false&gs_rn=21&gs_ri=psy-ab&gs_mss=toStrt&tok=q6vd9kmeBE_rB0WsAEVMPg&pq=tostring&cp=1&gs_id=co&xhr=t&q=javascript+tostring&es_nrs=true&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=jtoString&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49478099,d.dmg&fp=f7832418d1972726&biw=1214&bih=865) pulls up nothing useful in the first 10 or so hits.

Because it is on `Object.prototype`, it is accessible by global objects which inherit from Object ( only those that inherit, not all global objects ), such as Number.

But my point is, is that it is also accessible directly with out having to use a global object instance at all.

```
toString(some_var);
```

Here is one [SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669079/) which suggests that window.toString is not supported in all browsers and why this is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> global objects which inherit from Object,

That's a wrong assumption, [global objects are host objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1) and they can inherit from whatever they want or not inherit anything at all. The code for example doesn't work in IE10.

The *particular* `toString` method stored on `Object.prototype` is the only one that returns the internal class name for sure. Functions, arrays, numbers etc do not inherit the `Object.prototype` `toString` method but define their *own* `toString` method, as in `Number.prototype.toString !== Object.prototype.toString`.

Comment: Window does not inherit from Object.  That is not assumption that is a fact.  Number for example inherits from Object.  Window does not.  Does that make sense?  Do you understand the qualification I made.

Comment: @stack_temp you claimed that global object inherits from Object, that's what I am even quoting.

Comment: `is the only one that returns the internal class name for sure` That's not true. It can be overriden.

Comment: @stack: no, you were here to ask a question, which appears to have been effectively answered. I'm not sure I understand your need to criticise the English skills of someone that's taken their time to help you.

Comment: @freakish the property can be overriden but not the function, never said that about a property.

Comment: How do you want to access a function which was overriden before? The point is that it cannot be a reason. Even more, it seems that (at least under Chrome) that `toString` global cannot be overriden.

Comment: @freakish you can create an iframe for example and get the function from there

Comment: You have misunderstood greatly, I said that there is only one function that gives internal class name for sure and that is the toString function *referenced* from Object.prototype.toString, I never said that the property is read-only or something.

Comment: Right, but it does not answer the question: why `Object.prototype.toString` instead of `toString`? If I understand it correctly. The `toString` global is a reference to the same function, but it is better since you cannot override it (at least under Chrome).

Comment: @freakish I say that right away - because it is only accidentally a reference to the same function (due to global object being a host object, there are no guarantees, just accidents) and for example doesn't work in IE10. ?

Comment: @Esailija Yeah, you're right. I even installed IE10 to check this. It's weird because there is a global `toString` function but it seems that it always returns `"[object]"` string. As usual I have no idea what's going on in IE. :)